# Integração entre sistemas com PHP

Tags: php, json, xml, post, get

Preciso disponibilizar um serviço para outros sistemas consumirem.
Estes sistemas podem fazer requisições `POST` (string, array, xml e json) e `GET`.
Bom, eu sei que consigo consumir serviços de outros sistemas usando `GET` de forma trivial, apenas acessando uma `URL`, e quanto às requisições `POST`, eu consigo passar os dados para o sistema que fornece o serviço através de `CURL`.

Bom, agora quem precisa disponibilizar o serviço sou eu , e não sei bem qual a melhor forma de se fazer.

Conheci as metodologias/especificações de `webservices` `Rest`, o que seria interessante para mim, porém eu preciso de uma solução mais rápida.
Não tenho afinidade com `WebServices`, e todo o material que eu encontrei na internet mencionava frameworks como: `NodeJS`, `Ruby On Rails` e `Django`.

Não posso implementar `NodeJS` apenas para esse propósito.
No `GitHub` até encontrei uma classe, mas não consegui entender exatamente o seu propósito.

Gostaria de encontrar uma solução para fazer essa integração.

Comment: Acredito que seja contraditório falar em "fazer rápido" e "melhor forma" na mesma questão, mas vamos ver que tipos de respostas podem aparecer.

Comment: Pode existir mais de uma forma de fazer, e se tiver, qual é a mais rápida.
Talvez poderíamos interpretar assim, não ?

Comment: Se podes usar algo novo, dá uma olhada no [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com), vai te ajudar no que precisas.

Answer (score 1):

@William, Talvez este link abaixo te ajude. Acredito que a melhor forma de trocar informações entre sistemas possa ser usando API.

http://imasters.com.br/linguagens/php/aprenda-a-usar-o-restful-com-php-e-slim-framework